# Python 3 how to write unit tests for try except outside functions in modules

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-module, python-unittest.mock

I would like to know how to write Python 3 unittest for `try except`blocks
that are defined outside of function definitions in Python's module.

Imagine that in `package/module.py` I have a block of code like:

import os

```
try:
  CONSTANT = os.environ['NOT_EXISTING_KEY']
except KeyError:
  CONSTANT = False
finally:
  del os
```

(please don't mind the actual code, I know I could have used `os.getenv('NOT_EXISTING_KEY', False)`in this specific case, what I am interested in is really testing that the try-except block in a module (outside of a function) behaves as expected.

How can I write a unit test that checks that `package.module.CONSTANT` is set to the expected value?

In the unittest file (I use pytest) I have something like:

```
from package.module import CONSTANT

def test_constant_true():
  assert CONSTANT == 'expected_value'
```

to test that if the try block executed correctly then CONSTANT is as expected.

I don't know, however, how to mock the import machinery so that the os.environ in the try block raises an exception and I can test that CONSTANT is set to False.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried `monkeypatch.setenv()`?

Comment: Use `mock` or a custom monkeypatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `monkeypatch` to set the environment variable, but you have to reload the module for the change to take effect:

```
from importlib import reload

from package import module


def test_constant_true(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv('MY_KEY', '42')
    reload(module)
    assert module.CONSTANT == '42'


def test_constant_false():
    reload(module)
    assert not module.CONSTANT
```

Given this content of `package/module.py`:

```
import os

try:
    CONSTANT = os.environ['MY_KEY']
except KeyError:
    CONSTANT = False
```

Comment: I think the answer could be improved by using a mock that raises the desired error to test that the exception is caught correctly but the "reload" function was the key I needed to solve my issue, many thanks!

Comment: I would argue that the exception is an implementation detail that needs not to be tested - the relevant part is the set variable - but that is of course opinion-based. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You could mock the environment using `mock.patch.dict` and import the value inside your unit test method. Like so:

```py
from unittest import TestCase, mock

class YourTest(TestCase):
    @mock.patch.dict('os.environ', {'NOT_EXISTING_KEY': 'value'})
    def test_constant_key_defined(self, mocked):
        """ Tests when the key is defined """
        from package.module import CONSTANT
        self.assertEqual(CONSTANT, 'value')

    def test_constant_key_not_defined(self):
        """ Tests when the key is not defined """
        from package.module import CONSTANT
        self.assertEqual(CONSTANT, 'value')
```

You may use the `importlib.reload`, like @mrbean-bremen's answer, which I am not familiar with.

Comment: this wouldn't let me happen to test what happen when an error is raised though

Comment: If you want to test when the error is raised, simply remove the mock. Just create another method without the mock and do the same thing. I will update the answer.